# How do I style my breadcrumb to fit in one line

Tags: html, css

I got the style of my breadcrumb here [bootstrapmade.com](https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/Flattern/)

however, the problem in my code is that the navigation is directly beneath the heading instead of being on the same line, how can I achieve this?

here's the css

```
.breadcrumbs {
padding: 15px 0;
background: #2b2320;
min-height: 40px;
}

.breadcrumbs h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
}

.breadcrumbs ol {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ded5d2;
}

.breadcrumbs ol a {
    color: #fe825a;
}

.breadcrumbs ol li+li {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.breadcrumbs ol li+li::before {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #c8bab5;
    content: "/";
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .breadcrumbs .d-flex {
        display: block !important;
    }

    .breadcrumbs ol {
        display: block;
    }

    .breadcrumbs ol li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

here's the html

```
<section id="breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumbs">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <h2>Apply</h2>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Careers">Careers</a></li>
                    <li>Apply</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Please Help i tried changing align-items-center to align-items-baseline and it didnt help, I also tried wrapping the h2 and ol in a div with class row, it also didnt work. in css I tried flex-direction row and it also didnt work

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: I think your question have been solved so why are you not accepting the answers? Accept all the answers that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay use flex in **".breadcrumbs .container > div"** this class. after all breadcrumbs content show in one line.
**Note : Output show in Full Screen**

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: #2b2320;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.breadcrumbs h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
}

.breadcrumbs ol {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ded5d2;
}

.breadcrumbs ol a {
    color: #fe825a;
}

.breadcrumbs ol li+li {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.breadcrumbs ol li+li::before {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #c8bab5;
    content: "/";
}


/* //CSS For set Breadcrumbs center on layout */

.breadcrumbs .container {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.breadcrumbs .container > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .breadcrumbs .d-flex {
        display: block !important;
    }

    .breadcrumbs ol {
        display: block;
    }

    .breadcrumbs ol li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumbs">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <h2>Apply</h2>
              <ol>
                  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Careers">Careers</a></li>
                  <li>Apply</li>
              </ol>
          </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I see, but bootstrap5 cdn is messing with my other css

Comment: okay, I update code in snippets you can check there.

Answer (score 0):

`I think you need to missed bootstrap cdn in your code that is why Breadcrumb is not in one line`

> > Stylesheet CDN :

```
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

> > Scriptisheet CDN

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

#### Including this cdn script linking in your html file will fix your problem.

###### Add the StyleSheet CDN inside `<head></head>`

###### Add the ScriptSheet CDN at the end of `<body></body>`

###### Use the following code

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: #2b2320;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.breadcrumbs h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.breadcrumbs ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ded5d2;
}

.breadcrumbs ol a {
  color: #fe825a;
}

.breadcrumbs ol li+li {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.breadcrumbs ol li+li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #c8bab5;
  content: "/";
}


/* //CSS For set Breadcrumbs center on layout */

.breadcrumbs .container {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.breadcrumbs .container>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .breadcrumbs .d-flex {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .breadcrumbs ol {
    display: block;
  }
  .breadcrumbs ol li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumbs">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <h2>Apply</h2>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Careers">Careers</a></li>
        <li>Apply</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This worked but it messed with my current css. Thank You.